# Trying to work out if $a^z$ is complex differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to work out if $f\left(z\right)=a^z$ is complex differentiable but I have never actually been taught any complex analysis and I am mostly using wikipedia and the internet in general to do research so I do not know if the approach I am taking is valid. I am trying to use the Cauchy–Riemann Equations as they seem to determine if a function is complex differentiable but I am not sure if my logic is sound. I created$$g\left(x,y\right)=a^{x+iy}$$$$=a^xa^{iy}$$$$=a^x\left(\cos \left(y\right)+\sin \left(y\right)i\right)$$$$=a^x\cos \left(y\right)+a^x\sin \left(y\right)i$$
From which I created $u\left(x,y\right)$ and $v\left(x,y\right)$

$$u\left(x,y\right)=a^x\cos \left(y\right)$$
$$v\left(x,y\right)=a^x\sin \left(y\right)$$

Which have partial derivatives
$$\frac{∂ u}{∂ x}=\ln \left(a\right)a^x\cos \left(y\right)$$
$$\frac{∂ v}{∂ y}=a^x\cos \left(y\right)$$

Which means that for $a\not=e\pm2π ni$ 
$$\frac{∂ u}{∂ x} \not= \frac{∂ v}{∂ y}$$

And so for $a\not=e±2π ni$ $f\left(x\right)$ is not complex differentiable. (Looking at $\frac{∂ v}{∂ x}$ and $\frac{∂ u}{∂ y}$ produces the same result so I have left that out here)

This seems reasonable but it is just not what I expected and I wanted to make sure that I haven't made any obvious mistakes. If you have any questions I will try to answer them to the best of my ability but as I said I have not actually been taught any of this so I might not know the answer.

Comment: $e^{iy}=\cos(y)+i \sin(y)$

Comment: Thanks. I will look at this again

Comment: Okay so looking at it again using $a^{iy}=cos(ln(a)y)+isin(ln(a)y)$ I get that $a^z$ is complex differentiable for all $a$. However I used the identity $a^{b}=e^{ln(a)b}$ which the wikipedia article on exponentiation seems to imply is not valid when using complex exponentiation even when using a multivalued $ln(a)$, is this correct.

Comment: This needs a little bit of clarification: first thing: is $a$ real or complex? 
By the way, if $a$ is real, this last remark you made is the right observation and the conclusion is valid.

Comment: I am mainly interested in the case when $a$ is real and negative but I am also interested in what happens for any complex $a$.@AlessioRanallo.

Comment: Okay so from what I can tell this implies that for all non-real $a$, $a^z$ is not complex differentiable and for all real $a$, $a^z$ is complex differentiable. Okay, thanks. I am just curious, does the fact that negative real numbers do not have a real natural logarithm not affect whether $a^z$ for negative $a$ is complex differentiable. If not why not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(z) = e^z$ is differentiable for all $z \in \Bbb C$. And if given any differentiable $f$ and constant $k, f'(kz) = kf'(z)$. Hence $e^{kz}$ is also differentiable.

The problem is not that $a^z$ is not differentiable for non-real or negative real $a$. The problem is that just saying "$a^z$" isn't sufficient to define a function.

We can define $e^z$ for complex $z$ by a number of different means. The most obvious is to define it by the Taylor series:
$$e^z := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

For other bases $a$, we can find a $k$ such that $a = e^k$, and define $a^z = e^{kz}$. The flaw in this is that $e^{k + 2n\pi i} = a$ as well for any integer $n$. So there is not one such value of $k$ but inifinitely many, and in general $e^{kz} \ne e^{(k + 2n\pi i)z}$, so you get different functions for different choices of the coefficient $k$.

Note that this holds even for positive real $a$. In fact, it holds even when $a = e$. For all of them, there are actually infinitely many exponential functions that we could define. However, for positive real $a$, exactly one of the potential values of $k$ is itself a real number, and we exploit this fact to select this real value of $k$ as the preferred one. Hence by convention (not because it is the only choice), we get $a^z = e^{z\ln a}$ for positive real $a$.

But when $a$ is negative or not real, there is no such preferred value of $k$. There remains an infinite number of possible definitions for $a^z$. Without additional information - something that specifies exactly which constant $k$ is being used - the function is not well-defined.

However, if you do finish the definition by choosing the coefficient $k$ (either directly or by imposing some condition that only one value of $k$ will satisfy), at that point $a^z = e^{kz}$ is well-defined and indeed is differentiable for all $z$.

Comment: Thanks. This has been incredibly useful. Using the definition of $a^z$ you gave I checked that it was indeed complex differentiable using the Cauchy-Riemann equations just because I wanted to be careful. This has solved my problem elegantly so thank you.